# Synchronize two projects (synchronize used framework)

Tags: svn

I prepare couple of sites based on the same framework. From time to time I change something in that framework. How to synchronize those changes among other projects based on the same framework? Is a SVN capable of doing this? Bonus question: is PHPStorm capable of doing this?

What I'm trying to achive is: changes in framework in one project should be synchronized with all other projects based on the same framework. So whatever which one project is modified, every other project should be modified aswell (automatically or manually - it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** your framework have own special separate location inside site and you don't mix it with implementation-specific objects inside any common dir

you have to use svn-externals:

From single physical location framework will be "mounted" to any amount of "logical" locations inside sites repositories and updates in framework will be automatically reflected on all targets

PS: Reading SVN Book is useful thing

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about SVN, but you can use `git`. In that case you simply use three repositories:

- Repository for project A;
- Repository for project B;
- Repository for the library.

You can then use a submodule that is a git repository in a git-repository. If you push changes from the first submodule to the remote, you can pull the from the second remote.

I wrote some bash scripts who does the synchronization of submodules among several repositories automatically each six hours.

Comment: This isn't git propaganda. Svn is a wonderful tool, I've worked several years with it. But in my opinion it is somehow outdated. I don't blame svn. It's always easier to do a better job if you can learn from the "mistakes" from other systems.

Comment: All right, what is the problem with git? Such a small comment is easy. In my opinion distributed subversioning systems that use branches very fluently are an improvement. Especially for projects with 100+ contributors. I remember those days when you needed more than an hour to resolve a conflict and finally came to the conclusion that it was hard to revert to the original version. Git definitely improved that part... If you look at this page http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=git%2C%20svn you see that svn reached its peak and git is a natural successor.